# Play Framework 2.4 routing: one route for multiple urls Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I have admin part in my project which use React.js and React router. 
And I need to render the same view on each request which starts with /admin in case user hit Refresh or come straight to url. 
I don't need to pass any parameters to view. How can it be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-capturing wildcards in Play Framework routes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975794/non-capturing-wildcards-in-play-framework-routes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your route like this in play:

```
/admin/*url                controllers.Application.admin(url)
```

Comment: I don't need this url parameter in action. Is this possible without using parameter?

Comment: Try emitting `url` on the method call.